# Delphi - TBitBtn- Invalid image size error

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Using: Delphi XE2 Update 4.1

On the form, TImageList with 12x12 images is linked to TActionManager. When selecting the 'Action' property of a TBitBtn on the form, it shows 'Invalid image size' error.

Screenshot attached:
[image]

Is there limitation on the Glyph sizes that can be attached to BitBtn? If so, its not mentioned in the Help documentation.

Comment: It sounds like you somehow have an image in the image list with dimensions different from what's specified on the image list itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means a `TGraphic` image was passed to the `TImageList` but the graphic's `Height` was less than the `TImageList.Height`, or the graphic's `Width` was less than the `TImageList.Width`.  There are four conditions where a `TGraphic` is validated by `TImageList`:

1. `TCustomImageList.GetImageHandle()`, which is called by `TCustomImageList.Add()`, `TCustomImageList.AddMasked()`, and `TCustomImageList.Replace()`
2. `TCustomImageList.AddIcon()`
3. `TCustomImageList.ReplaceMasked()`
4. `TCustomImageList.ReplaceIcon()`

In your case, `AddIcon()` is being called, so clearly the dimensions of the icon being added to the `TImageList` are too small.